# Js: customize #tag value generated by field name 'via' in addthis twitter share JS Plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter, addthis, add-this-event

i need to share a hashtag (example: #myPlutonicHash) from my website to twitter account. i have used addThis javascript object present in **addThis plugin Feature**, as shown below

```
var addthis_share = {};
addthis_share = {
title : 'PlutonicTitle',
passthrough : {
    twitter: {
        via: "#myPlutonicHash"
    }
}
};
```

From my website, When i click  twitter icon to share the title of my website and required #tag, i get the following output which is the **default text output format** when used field 'via' in twitter textbox.

```
Output1
PlutonicTitle via @#myPlutonicHash
```

But, i dont need the text 'via' and '@' in my twitter text box. i need to customize the default text output format of field 'via'
.
**My required text output is shown below**.

```
Output2
PlutonicTitle #myPlutonicHash
```

kindly help me out in getting my required output.

Comment: Twitter is very particular in how it wants it content displayed on third-party sites. I don't think you can change it. Also you cannot share via hashtag. Twitter shares have to pass through a user account. Hashtags are just a way of grouping tweets. Add this specifically mentions that it has to be a username: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/683399-changes-to-how-twitter-works-with-addthis

Comment: @Zealander so there is no way to display as i have shown in Output2(see my post). Does addThis have fields other than 'via' to accomplish my requirement of dislpaying #tags? . BTW, addThis just shares the text to a loggedin twitter account, addThis feature iam using doesnot display content elsewhere

Comment: I don't think so, @Lyon. I've had to implement a few twitter widgets myself and I know they're very rigid. It has to say "via @" that's for sure. Twitter wants it's branded content displayed uniformly throughout the web. Keep this post, perhaps someone has a different opinion, but it's unlikely.

Comment: @Zealander thanks dude. i have seen many shared twitter #tags in twitter site , the way i require, but not sure whether those people have used addThis feature to accomplish those.

Comment: @Zealander hi, just view the accepted answer. it works. i thot it might be of some help for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Here's how to do it:

```
var addthis_share = {};
addthis_share = {
title : 'PlutonicTitle',
passthrough : {
    twitter: {
        hashtags: "myPlutonicHash"
    }
}
};
```

If you want more than one hash tag, separate them with commas like this:

```
var addthis_share = {};
addthis_share = {
title : 'PlutonicTitle',
passthrough : {
    twitter: {
        hashtags: "myPlutonicHash,myOtherPlutonicHash"
    }
}
};
```

If you've got more questions send us an email at help@addthis.com